# Certain types of images aren't displayed correctly in HTML

Tags: html, frontend

I'm new to front end development and am trying to display images from this API https://dash.valorant-api.com/endpoints/agents.

While images such as https://media.valorant-api.com/agents/5f8d3a7f-467b-97f3-062c-13acf203c006/displayicon.png work fine with the `<img>` tag, images such as:

https://media.valorant-api.com/agents/5f8d3a7f-467b-97f3-062c-13acf203c006/abilities/ability1/displayicon.png

https://media.valorant-api.com/agents/5f8d3a7f-467b-97f3-062c-13acf203c006/abilities/ability2/displayicon.png

Just show whitespace when I try to load them into the website, I understand it's something to do with the type of images, but I don't how to display them correctly.

Comment: can you provide screenshots with the scenarios and what the console is saying press f12 in crome and see if there is an error

Comment: Your last URL is not a valid image. I have an error message when I open it
https://media.valorant-api.com/agents/5f8d3a7f-467b-97f3-062c-13acf203c006/abilities/ability3/displayicon.png

Comment: @Eduard yup, I seem to have copied the wrong link, I'll edit it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check up your html background color (ex: body { background-color: black; }, maybe its because you have white background color and two of the images are white symbols. By the way, the last photo does not work in any way. It returns an error with de api.

Comment: Add a code snippet using the API/URL mention in question. So that your answer will be more clear and helpful.

Comment: It seams that his problem is more related with a background color more than an API issue

Comment: yup, this was the problem, I changed the background of the div that the image was in to darkgrey and I could see the icon. Thank you!